# Unable to fit an ECDF using scipy.optimize.curve_fit

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I'm tring to approximate an empirical cumulative distribution function ([ECDF I want to approximate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6bFD.png)) with a smooth function (with less than 5 parameter) such as the **generalized logistic function**.

However, using `scipy.optimize.curve_fit`, the fitting operation gives really bad approximations or it doesn't work at all (depending on the initial values). The variable `series` represents my data stored as `pandas.Series`.

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def fit_ecdf(x):
    x = np.sort(x)
    def result(v):
        return np.searchsorted(x, v, side='right') / x.size
    return result

ecdf = fit_ecdf(series)

def genlogistic(x, B, M, Q, v):
    return 1 / (1 + Q * np.exp(-B * (x - M))) ** (1 / v)

params = curve_fit(genlogistic, xdata = series, ydata = ecdf(series), p0 = (0.1, 10.0, 0.1, 0.1))[0]
```

Should I use another type of function for the fit?
Are there any code mistakes?

**UPDATE - 1**

As asked, I link to a csv containing [the data](https://ufile.io/irtm7).

**UPDATE - 2**

After a lot of search and trial and error I find out this function

```
f(x; a, b, c) = 1 - 1 / (1 + (x / b) ** a) ** c
with a = 4.61320000, b = 2.94570952, c = 0.5886922
```

which fits a lot better than the other one. The only problem is the little step that the ECDF shows near `x=1`. How can I modify `f` to improve the quality of the fit? I was thinking of adding some sort of function that is "relevant" only in those kind of points. Here are the graphical results of the fit where the solid blue line is the ECDF and the dotted line represents the `(x, f(x))` points.

[image: Here are the graphical results of the fit]

Comment: Could you provide a reduced sample of your data?(see [mcve]) so it's possible to test a solution suitable for it

Comment: For large `x` your function approaches `1`, but I guess you want `(0,0)` as well. Is that happening for reasonable `M,Q`? I have the impression one should look at the fit function again.

Comment: @xdze2 I update a sample of the data.
@mikuszefski It's not strictly necessary for the function to have root at `x=0`. It can return a small value as well as I pretend for large `x` that the function goes to `1`.

Comment: I suggest visual inspection of a scatterplot for the data you are passing to curve_fit().

Comment: @JamesPhillips the function seems ok, but apparently doesn't fit the data very well. I'm corrently tring to approximate the ECDF with another function that works much better. However I want to improve the fit near the `x=1`.

Comment: I added the graphical results and the parameters for the function. Sorry, at first I forgot to add them.

Comment: The data in the link you posted does not seem to match the data in your image. Can you please post a link to the data in the image?

Comment: @JamesPhillips The csv was containing a random sample of the data, so some strong outliers weren't included due to their small frequency. Now, as you asked, I uploaded all the data (800k points). Hope it helps.

Comment: This is the same data as in the image you posted, as I requested? The posted image does not appear to contain 800k points.

Comment: @JamesPhillips Yes sure, it does. The graph is done using matplotlib and seaborn. If you want I can post the code too. It probably seems that there are less points because a lot of them have the same value.

Comment: With some points having more duplicate values than others, you will be in effect weighting the fit towards those data points. I suggest a test where you average the values of the duplicate points and analyzing those regression results to see if the implicit weighting of the data makes any difference.

Comment: Thank you very much. I forgot that duplicate values must be considered when computing the EDCF (of course), but not when considering the regression problem. I've tried to use unique points for the regression (so I took only one value from every duplicates group) but makes basically no difference. Parameters shift a tiny bit, but there are no graphical changes, expecially around `x=1`.

Comment: Excellent that you have proof of this now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find out how to deal with that little step near `x=1`. As expressed in the question, adding some sort of function that is significant only in that interval was the game changer.
The "step" ends at about `(1.7, 0.04)` so I needed a sort of function that flattens for `x > 1.7` and has `y = 0.04` as asymptote. The natural choice (just to stay on point) was to take a function like `f(x) = 1/exp(x)`.
Thanks to JamesPhillips, I also picked up the proper data for the regression (no double values = no overweighted points).

**Python Code**

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def fit_ecdf(x):
    x = np.sort(x)
    def result(v):
        return np.searchsorted(x, v, side = 'right') / x.size
    return result

ecdf = fit_ecdf(series)

unique_series = series.unique().tolist()

def cdf_interpolation(x, a, b, c, d):
    f_1 = 0.95 + (0 - 0.95) / (1 + (x / b) ** a) ** c + 0.05
    f_2 = (0 - 0.05)/(np.exp(d * x))
    return f_1 + f_2

params = curve_fit(cdf_interpolation, 
                   xdata = unique_series , 
                   ydata = ecdf(unique_series), 
                   p0 = (6.0, 3.0, 0.4, 1.0))[0]
```

**Parameters**

```
a = 6.03256462 
b = 2.89418871 
c = 0.42997956
d = 1.06864006
```

**Graphical results** 
[image: ECDF & Inferred CDF]

Answer (score 0):

I got an OK fit for a 5-parameter logistic equation (see image and code) using unique values, not sure if the low end curve is sufficient for your needs, please check.
[image]

```
import numpy as np

def Sigmoidal_FiveParameterLogistic_model(x_in): # from zunzun.com

    # coefficients
    a = 9.9220221252324947E-01
    b = -3.1572339989462903E+00
    c = 2.2303376075685142E+00
    d = 2.6271495036080207E-02
    f = 3.4399008905318986E+00

    return d + (a - d) / np.power(1.0 + np.power(x_in / c, b), f)
```

Comment: The fit for `x>2.5` is great. However using a sigmoidal function with 5 parameters you let infer the asymptotes too (`a` and `d`). This setup is kinda strange since we know that the points that we are using for the interpolation represent a ECDF. In fact, looking at the graph and the parameters, the main inconsistency is that the sigmoid has `y=d=0.026` as lower asymptote. So for `x=0` you get something like `y = 0.026` instead of `0`. You avoid the "step" problem, but you build up a function that doesn't behave like a CDF for lower `x` values.

Comment: I fit with the lower asymptote forced to zero, and the low end fit poorly. My suggestion is to use two equations that fit to overlapping data ranges, such as fitting below 2.5 for the low end and greater than 2.0 for the high end,  using these as switching between the two when data is above or below he center of the overlap region. You can likely find a function with less than five parameters for each equation as well. I can again use my zunzun.com "function finder" for equation search if this idea seems reasonable to you.

Comment: For my purposes, I think the solution with the sum of two function is better than dividing the data points in two and applying for each segment a different function. Thank you very much anyway.